# Fade in with JQuery Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to fade in the page upon load. I looked at other forms on here and somehow it just isnt working for me...

Javascript file:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    $('#container').fadeIn('slow');

}
```

One of the pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Apparel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
                <script src="effects.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>
     <div id="cart">
        <img src="shopcart.jpg" height="30px">
     </div>

     <div id="container">   
        <div id="nav"> 
            <p id="sb">Apparel</p>
            <p id="about"><a href="home.html">HOME</a></p>          
            <p id="srv"><a href="outerwear.html">OUTERWEAR</a></p>
            <p id="srv"><a href="clothing.html">CLOTHING</a></p>
            <p id="pjt"><a href="shoes.html">SHOES</a></p>
            <p id="pjt"><a href="accessories.html">ACCESSORIES</a></p>
            <p id="about"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></p>
            <p id="cont"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></p>
        </div>

        <div id="imgcontainer">
            <img src="homeimg.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: to work with jQuery, you need to include jQuery library before your script

Comment: Also, `$(document).ready` is the suggested way to do `window.onload` in jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Put

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

above

`<script src="effects.js"></script>`

This exposes the `$` variable (aka the jQuery library) that you're using when you do `$('#container')`

Comment: **Note:** If you do what @msm8bball suggests, you cannot take advantage of an end-user already having Google's CDN version of jQuery in their cache. (Therefore, each user will **always** have to download your version on their first visit)

Comment: Yes, true. CDN hosted is preferred. In some cases (such as building internal intranet sites) however CDN's are not options. Appears this is a shopping site though, so probably it's a public site. Just wanted to make sure he was aware of the option.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better replace the window.onload to $(function(){});

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//window.onload = init;
$(function(){
   init()
});
</script>
```

Enjoy it : )